# Could not build Objective-C Module 'CoreFoundation'

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoa-touch, core-foundation, leveldb

I am having trouble with this issue after updating Firebase through CocoaPods.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Any Firebase Version beyond 4.0.2 causes the same error in Xcode (version 10.1).

The error:

Swift Compiler Error

- 'string' file not found
- could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'

Already tried:

- clean project
- add SDK manually
- removing level db and adding manually

Where is the issue? With the Swift file/header? With leveldb? Or Firebase?

Related (similar issue on GitHub, but the suggested solutions there do not work for me):

https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/515

Xcode message:

```
> <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from
> <module-includes>:1:
> #import "Headers/CoreFoundation.h"
>         ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:10:
> note: in file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
> #include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
>          ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:10:
> note: in file included from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
> #include <Block.h>
>          ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:10: note: in file
> included from /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode -
> projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:
> #include "leveldb/iterator.h"
>          ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:10:
> note: in file included from /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode -
> projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:
> #include "leveldb/slice.h"
>          ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/slice.h:21:10:
> error: 'string' file not found
> #include <string>
>          ^ <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
```